# Writing array vertically to CSV

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

I can't figure out how to write an array vertically down a column to my output CSV file. Writing an array horizontally is simple enough and can be done in one line:

```
CSV.open("log.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Computers",]
  csv << myarray
end
```

Is there any way to get `myarray` written down a column in one line, or is it more complicated than that?

Array format:
`["pc_0", "pc_1","pc_2"]`

Comment: can you please paste the value of `MyArray`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the input data (`MyArray`) and what you expect the output CSV to look like.

Comment: Try to replace `csv << MyArray` with `MyArray.each { |e| csv << e }`. BTW, an array starting with a captial letter looks strange in Ruby.

Comment: @Geoffrey See, that's useful information. Your question gave no indication that your array is a flat array of strings (and not, say, a two-dimensional array, as is common with tabular data destined for a CSV file). Kind of an important detail. When people who want to help you ask for more information it's expedient to just give it to them instead of arguing about whether they need it or not. They probably have a good reason for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your array and add each item to the CSV as an array:

```
CSV.open("log.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [ "Computers" ]
  MyArray.each do |item|
    csv << [ item ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Marshal dump to serialize array then convert string to insert csv.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the array with `each`.

```
CSV.open("log.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Computers"]
  myArray.each { |e| csv << e }
end
```

If you have several arrays to put into the CSV file, you could use `zip` to put all together in on array.

```
CSV.open("log.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Computers","OS","RAM"]
  arr = myComputers.zip(myOperatingSystems, myRams)
  arr.each { |row| csv << row }
end
```